# Can I go to page anchor onload without Javascript

Tags: html, css, anchor

When I click on the Page number it shows the right text.
But the page loads blank.

Can I use the onload to force the page to show #Page01 directly.

Note: Trying to steer clear of javascript. Can this be done with HTML and CSS?

One workaround is use php and bounce it with index.php on from a bounce page like
http://example.com/thebouncepage
with this

```
<?php
die ('<META http-equiv="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=http://example.com/therealpage/#Page01">');
?>
```

It works, but it's not a tidy fix. This is the style and body that I would like to show Page 1 on load. Currently it loads blank.

```
<style>
.pageit{
  display: none;
}
.pageit:target {
  display: block;
}
</style>
<body>
<a href="#Page01">Page 1</a><br />
<a href="#Page02">Page 2</a><br />
<a href="#Page03">Page 3</a><br />
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="pageit" id="Page01">
                    This is text 1
        </td>
    </tr>                                               
    <tr>
        <td class="pageit" id="Page02">
                    This is text 2
        </td>
    </tr>                                               
    <tr>
        <td class="pageit" id="Page03">
                    This is text 3
        </td>
    </tr>                                               
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: You could just redirect the site url to url#Page01

Answer (score 0):

Im sure this isn't the best solution but the simplest one I can think of

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url='#page01'" />
```

add this code to your index.html